# Optimize Hive table loading time in spark

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a spark streaming project in which incoming stream join with multiple Hive tables. So I am loading the table in spark and cache it.

Below is the given sample query-

```
 val df = sql("select * from (select *, row_number() over (partition by a , b , c, d order by date desc) row_num from test) tmp where tmp.row_num = 1")
```

The table has 99% duplicate data, so I am using row number logic to get distinct. When I did `df.explain(true)` there is no condition in pushdown. So whole table load in memory. The table has billions of data. which gives `FAILED_TO_UNCOMPRESS(5)` error.

Should I create Hive view using the above query and call the view in spark so it will fetch resultant data. I don't know if it works.

There are about 10 tables which loads in spark every 15 minutes. All have the same row number logic. How can enable the pushdown? So spark can only fetch the resultant data from Hive.

Comment: Quick question would a,b,c,d,date create a unique record?

Comment: Hi @lucy the question is about what query to use or how to enable push-down filtering in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the *MAX* function instead of *ROW_NUM* ? The use of ROW_NUM could be the issue. I would use the following query :

```
val df = sql("select *, MAX(date) over (partition by a , b , c, d) from test")
```

See [*MAX* function definition](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_max.html) for more details.

Comment: lots of duplicate records are getting

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate ? this query ensures that tuple (date, a, b, c,d) is unique